# How can i get HTTP Authorization header

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, http-headers, xmlhttprequest, httprequest

I am developing a Chrome extension to capture the Authentication information. I want to get the HTTP Authorization Header.

I tried the Chrome API `webRequest.onSendHeaders`, but it didn't work

following is my code:

```
/***************onsendHeaders*************/
chrome.webRequest.onSendHeaders.addListener(function(details) {
    console.log(details.url, details.requestHeaders);
    for(var i = 0; i < details.requestHeaders.length;i++) {
        var header = details.requestHeaders[i];
        if(header.name.toLowerCase() == "authorization") {
        alert("AUTH!");                      /*Never get alert when I login to websites*/
        }
    }
},
{"urls":["*://*/*"]},
["requestHeaders"]);
```

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest.html#event-onAuthRequired

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But this 'onAuthRequired' only fires when authentication failure received. For example, I login to Facebook with the valid account, this will not fire. How can I use it to get authorizatoin header? @RobW

Comment: Does Facebook really use HTTP authorization..? I have never seen such a thing.

Comment: :)I'm a starter.Then how can I recognise an authentication to FB by looking into the HTTP request?@RobW

Comment: General steps to get this information: 1. Open the developer tools (F12), network tab. 2. Login on the website. 3. Read the request details in the network tab.

Comment: To test whether your code really doesn't work, you need to test it on a request that actually uses basic HTTP authentication. That is **really rare**, authorization is usually done with cookies nowadays. Here's a test page for you: https://www.httpwatch.com/httpgallery/authentication/

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible to do inside an extension. It would be a security nightmare.

Xan comment below gave a nice [reference](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#life_cycle_footnote).

Comment: One can argue that `webRequest` API is a security nightmare. But it's just a powerful tool.

Comment: @Xan: the answer is that it isn't possible.

Comment: In case of the authorization header, you are correct: it is filtered by `webRequest`. It would be better if you [cited something](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#life_cycle_footnote), or at least claimed to have tested it. Now I did both.